# how to send array in post using codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

i have sent arrays in codeigniter framework according to the following:

```
for (var i=1; i<=selected; i++) {
           <div style="float: left; padding-left: 13px; padding-right: 12px; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 0px;">'+i+'
</div>
<input type="text" name="unitName[]" id="unitName'+i+'" style="width:189px;" required />
<input type="text" name="ownerName[]" id="ownerName'+i+'" style="width:241px;" />
<input type="text" name="salutation[]" id="salutation'+i+'" style="width:137px;" /><br />
       }
```

when i try to post it using following:

```
$ownerNames = $this->input->post('ownerName');
if (is_array($ownerNames)) {
    foreach( $ownerNames as $ownerName ) {
    echo "Owner Name is : " . $ownerName;
    }
} else {echo "Owner is not array";}
```

this is my entire controller, with all the posting:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                    $this->load->view('newblock');
                } else {
                    $registrarName = $this->input->post('registrarName');
                    $blockName = $this->input->post('blockName');
                    $serviceType = $this->input->post('serviceType');
                    $number = $this->input->post('number');
                    $email = $this->input->post('email');
                    $address1 = $this->input->post('address1');
                    $address2 = $this->input->post('address2');
                    $address3 = $this->input->post('address3[]');
                    $town = $this->input->post('town');
                    $postCode = $this->input->post('postCode');
                    $blockUnits = $this->input->post('blockUnits');


                    echo print_r($_POST);

                    $unitNames = $this->input->post('unitName', TRUE);
                    echo $unitNames[0].'<br />';
                    if (is_array($unitNames)) {
                        foreach( $unitNames as $unitName ) {
                        echo "unit Name is : " . $unitName;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "unit is not array";
                    }


                    $ownerNames = $this->input->post('ownerName', TRUE);
                    echo $ownerNames[0].'<br />';
                    if (is_array($ownerNames)) {
                        foreach( $ownerNames as $ownerName ) {
                        echo "Owner Name is : " . $ownerName;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Owner  is not array";
                    }


                    $salutations = $this->input->post('salutation', TRUE);
                    echo $salutations[0].'<br />';
                    if (is_array($salutations)) {
                        foreach( $salutations as $salutation ) {
                        echo "salutation is : " . $salutation;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "salutation  is not array";
                    }
```

it is displaying  "Owner is not an array"; which indicates the array is empty, after debugging i found by using print_r, that array was indeed empty, nothing was posted...

Comment: http://www.php.net/serialize :)

Comment: i dont get it. What is the problem

Comment: before the first line of the code you have wrote here, try to `print_r($_POST)` just to check if you have your data as array.

Comment: and for your information, `is_array` check if the var is an array or not. It does not check if the array is empty.

Comment: give us your entiere HTML code. you shoul have your input HTMLElement in a form etc...

Comment: I've looked up an old project, this works just fine on my end: `foreach ($_POST['ownerName'] as $value) { echo $value.'<br />'; }`. If that does not work, there is something else going on. There is either something happening to the $_POST data somewhere else in your code, something that CodeIgniter fails to do, or (smallest chance) there is a bug in PHP.

Comment: i have other form elements also, everything is in the post array except this array element

Comment: can you add your entiere form ?

Comment: This is the most cleanest approach; `<form method="post" action="run_app.php"><input type="text" name="ownerName[]" /><input type="text" name="ownerName[]" /><input type="text" name="ownerName[]" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></form> <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; ?>` and works just fine. Make sure if you debug that you check what happens to the form (maybe JavaScript interferes) or POST data gets edited when retrieving it inside your controller. Output: `Array ( [ownerName] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => ghi ) [Submit] => Submit )`

Comment: If you want to let us search and maybe find what's wrong, you have to give us the maximum input. In your case, the entire form at least

Comment: Please check the clean example on your server (singular file outside CodeIgniter) and see if at least it works in general. Otherwise it's really something in your own code that breaks the $_POST data.

Comment: This is codeigniter project so $_POST is out the question and reference here, all i am asking is why $this->input->post('unitName', TRUE); is not working

Comment: Are you sure that the missing input are in the form (on the HTML) ? I don't see the form tag in the piece of your HTML code

Comment: `$_POST` out of the question? That CodeIgniter input library is exactly the same as `$_POST`, just with some extra features.. If you don't debug from a certain root, you will never get to your problem.

Comment: yes they are in the html, i have seen it using firebug. Everything is fine in this view class

Comment: i have also done using $_POST, but still the array is empty

Comment: can you `print_r($_POST);die();` at the begin of your controller (on the part when the form is validated), and add the result of the print_r

Comment: it is just displaying the only the posted elements from registrarName to blockUnits only, nothing after that

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26612/matrtroom

Comment: This was a legitimate question, why the down voting, now i am banned from questioning, please upvote it...

Answer (score 6):

try this

test controller

```
  $ownerNames = $this->input->post('ownerName');
  if (is_array($ownerNames)) {
    foreach ($ownerNames as $ownerName => $k) {
      echo "Owner Name is : " . $k . "<br/>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Owner is not array";
  }
```

and test view

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
  <input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
  <input type="text" name="ownerName[]" />
  <input type="submit" value="ownerName" />
</form>
```

// Output

```
Owner Name is : name1
Owner Name is : name2
Owner Name is : name3
```

Comment: no effect, array is still empty, the problem is somewhere in the posting

Comment: yes. it works. check your code.

Comment: Whoever downvoted; the answer is correct. Just because it's not working for the OP you shouldn't downvote unless the answer is utmost wrong. +1 to compensate

Comment: i ahve seen using firebug, the name is with [] brackets, and i have written exactly what you have, but still everything is posted except the element which is array

Comment: You have a vote down may be because your are not solving/searching the problem, you just wrote an equivalent code of @Human